# Truncate_only deprecated in SQL2008

Tags: sql, database

The following statement

```
BACKUP LOG [AMS_Prod_log] WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY
```

works fine in SQL Server 2005 but it doesn't with 2008. It seems truncate_only is deprecated in 2008. Could you please let me know how to achieve this in 2008? What care needs to be taken like backup... etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the list of features depreciated in SQL 2005 i.e. they will not be available in SQL 2008.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Your alternative is provided in the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can backup log to `nul` device:

```
BACKUP LOG [databaseName]  
TO DISK = 'nul:' WITH STATS = 10
```

This will mark transaction log as backed-up like `TRUNCATE_ONLY` option did. 
The `nul:` device is like *black hole* - so you could not restore from such backup.